# Pair $\times$ pair

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, notation

The problem is about probability density function.

Does the notation $(x,y) \in (0,1) \times (0,1)$ mean that

$(x,y) = (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)$ , or something else?

Comment: It means $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$.

Comment: On the right side, $(0,1)$ means an interval of the real line. On the left side, $(x,y)$ means a pair of numbers. This is an unfortunate overloading of notation.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you!

Comment: @Arthur Thank you, that's good to know.

Comment: By the way, $(x,y)\in\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}$ means $(x,y)\in\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$.

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you, that was what I was after.

Comment: OK, good. you can also write that as $(x,y)\in\{0,1\}^2$.

Comment: @RobPratt Got it. Thank you!